# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, http

Есть сайт - https://ru.namemc.com/ , на нём хоть и есть авторизация, но получать информацию об никнеймах(Мне это и нужно) возможно без авторизации, я даже удалял куки, но он всегда даёт мне возможность получить информацию об нике. 

Я пробовал сделать, как я всегда делал - через скачивание сайта с никнеймом в url через WebClient, но мне выдаёт Exception `System.Net.WebException: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."`
Пробовал использовать `UseDefaultCredentials` - Ничего не изменилось.

На одном из ответов человек рассказал об HttpClient, начал использовать его, но даже через него получаю Exception `System.AggregateException: "One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).)"`

Код:

```
    private readonly HttpClient client = new()
    private readonly Encoding encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    private readonly StringBuilder offset = new StringBuilder("https://ru.namemc.com/search?q=");
    public async Task<List<State>> Get(List<string> NNs)
    {
        List<State> states = new();
        for(int i = 0; i < NNs.Count; i += 1)
        {
            var result = await clientt.GetStringAsync(offset + NNs[i]);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Thread.Sleep(100000);
        }
        return states;
    }
```

Что я делаю не так?
Для теста - https://ru.namemc.com/search?q=Yotic

Comment: Скорее всего это связано с защитой сайта (после некоторого количества запросов), т.к. с 403 он также возвращает html страницу с captcha

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, ну, я пытаюсь хоть раз получить информацию, я могу пожертвовать временем или нацепить прокси. У вас получилось всё?

Comment: Получается единственный вариант - переписать на Selenium?

Comment: Данный сайт использует CloudFlare защиту от DDoS атак. Ее можно обойти, но нужно разобраться что и как она делает. Раньше были проекты по типу [CloudflareSolver](https://github.com/RyuzakiH/CloudflareSolverRe), которые позволяли подключением одного `Handler`'a обойти это все, но увы, давно заброшены, но, если очень хочется, то можете на основе исходников попробовать самостоятельно решить проблему. Есть еще [такой](https://github.com/FlareSolverr/FlareSolverrSharp) вариант (не пробовал), вроде как надо поднять прокси сервер, через который будет идти обход. Ну и последний вариант - браузер, да.

Answer (score 0):

Т.к этот сайт использует CloudFlare, а последний проект по его обходу был только в 2020(Работал до конца 2021), после чего CloudFlare выпустило обновление с полным фиксом.
Я решил использовать Selenium с драйвером с обходом.